# How to get large Excel table to paste into multiple slides using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am new to this forum, and new to VBA.  I am working with a very large Excel table (200+ rows) where I have added a code in to identify page breaks based on when a value changes in one of the columns.  I've figured out how to paste my range of data into a PowerPoint slide, but I need it to paste onto separate slides according to where/when the page break is set.

Here is my page break code:

```
Dim I As Long, J As Long
J = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
For I = J To 2 Step -1
    If Range("I" & I).Value <> Range("I" & I - 1).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("I" & I)
    End If
Next I
```

And here is what I have so far to get range into PowerPoint, but this pastes everything on one slide:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'Copy Range from Excel
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J5")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile



Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

'Center Object
  With myPresentation.PageSetup
    shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
    shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)


'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End With
```